# Python: Search for words before and after a pair of keywords

Tags: python, parsing

I use the following code to open a text file, remove the HTML, and search for words before and after a certain keyword:

```
import nltk
import re

text = nltk.clean_html(open('file.txt').read())
text = text.lower()

pattern = re.compile(r'''(?x) ([^\(\)0-9]\.)+ | \w+(-\w+)* |  \.\.\. ''')
text = nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern)

#remove the digits from text
text = [i for i in text if not i.isdigit()]

# Text is now a list of words from file.txt
# I now loop over the Text to find all words before and after a specific keyword

keyword = ['foreign']
for i, w in enumerate(text):  #it gives to the list items numbers
    if w in keyword:
        before_word = text[i-5:i-1] if i > 0 else ''
        before_word = ' '.join(word for word in before_word)
        after_word = text[i+1:i+5] if i+1 < len(text) else ''
        after_word = ' '.join(word for word in after_word)
        print "%s <%s> %s" % (before_word, w, after_word)
```

This codes works well if `keyword` is one word. But what if I want to find the 5 words before and after `'foreign currency'` ? The issue is that in `text` all words separated by a space is a different item in the `text` list. I can't do `keyword = ['foreign currency']`. How can I solve this issue?

Sample .txt file [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdpyvgsw01ac22z/Output2012.txt?dl=0)

Comment: can you show how ur inpu file look like and what is ur expected output

Comment: @Hackaholic I added a sample txt file. A sample of words to be found would be "can be adversely affected by foreign currency exchange rate fluctuations"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered a regex?

This will match and capture five words before, and five words after, *foreign currency*

```
((\w+ ){5})foreign currency(( \w+){5})
```

Edit: this regex breaks on things like tabs, quotes, commas, parentheses, etc. 
And the provided 'sample of words to be found' doesn't have 5 following words, so it wouldn't match that.

Here's an updated regex which is 5 words up to, and 1-5 words following, the phrase
uses 'non-space' characters separated by 'non-word' characters for the words,
and it captures as one group including the search text:

```
((\S+\W){5}foreign currency(\W\S+){1,5})
```

Otherwise, you could try:

1. Join the text all into one line, no newlines
2. Use `something = text.find('foreign currency')` to find the first position of that text
3. Count backwards from there, character by character looking for spaces, for 5 words
4. Count forwards from the end, character by character looking for spaces, for 5 words
5. Loop all of this, using `something = text.find('foreign currency', previous_end_pos)` to tell it to look starting after the end of the previous step, to find the next instance.

Comment: If I use your regex code, how can I keep the word `foreign currency`? The current regex only shows the 5 previous and 5 after words.

Comment: @Plug4 : It does, because you specifically asked for that: *"what if I want to find the 5 words before and after"*... anyway, I've updated my answer with an edited regex that captures the whole phrase with surrounding words, and matches more usefully against a wider range of text and characters.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Hmmm but for some reason: `re.findall('((\S+\W){5}foreign currency(\W\S+){1,5})', text)` freezes my PC... takes too long to search?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a variable for the number of words in the "keyword" and iterating through the text by that number of items at a time?